# ¿Cómo puedo hacer actualizaciones parciales de ciertos campos en mi documento?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy utilizando el controlador nativo de mongodb para un pequeño proyecto de API en el que deseo poder hacer actualizaciones de ciertos campos en un documento específico.
siendo el cuerpo de petición completo el siguiente:

```
{
    userId: "....",
    userName: "name",
    botName: "name",
}
```

el problema es que `$set` en updateOne actualiza todos los campos que especifique en el cuerpo de actualización, pues en la petición desde el servidor paso las variables sin importar si el cliente las especificó o no en el cuerpo, y deseo que sea mongodb sea el que reconozca si los valores son indefinidos o no, y utilice correspondientemente el valor pasado en el cuerpo o el que ya tenía almacenado en el documento. Algo similar a lo que hace por ejemplo IF NULL en sql. Estuve buscando y la verdad me complico bastante, y soy nuevo en mongodb, me preguntaba cómo podría hacerse eso, o si quiera si es posible hacerlo sin recurrir a código backend directamente, que ya empiezo a creer que será una mejor opción.

A pesar de ello mi pregunta es: ¿Será posible hacer ese tipo de comprobaciones para valores nulos y por defecto directamente con algún operador o similar en mongoDB?

Incluso recurrí a chatgpt y bingChat y terminaron engañándome o algo así, me parecía interesante lo del operador `$ifNull`, pero terminé confundiéndome más.

```
const chatbotDb = await connectToDatabase();
        const usersCollection = chatbotDb.collection("users");

        const result = await usersCollection.updateOne({idUser}, {
            "$set": {
                "userName": {"$ifNull": [userName, "pepito"]},
                "botName": {"$ifNull": [botName, "Prueba"]}
            }
})
```

Esto lo único que hace es guardar literalmente objetos con propiedades `$ifNull` y estas con arreglos.
[captura de base de datos en mongodb compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEXgt.png)

Comment: "pues en la petición desde el servidor paso las variables sin importar si el cliente las especificó o no en el cuerpo". Como tienes el código de esta peticion?

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo mas claro del cuerpo que quieres pasar y el resultado que esperas obtener?

Comment: @Pipe el cuerpo de la petición es el siguiente:
``{
    userId: "....",
    userName: "name",
    botName: "name",
}``
Lo que deseo es poder realizar modificaciones de ciertos atributos o propiedades de un documento parcialmente, por ejemplo digamos que deseo cambiar botName por 'Juan', pues si yo hiciera lo siguiente:
`{
    "botName": "Juan"
}`
Al enviar dicho cuerpo en la solicitud, al no especificar los otros campos, mongodb por defecto coloca los otros atributos a null, pues desde el backend, siempre obtengo dichos atributos, sean definidos en el cuerpo o no.

Comment: Entonces si creo que te estás enredando mucho... Porque no procesas los datos antes de hacer la petición a mongo?

Comment: Al final terminé haciendo algo similar, decidí solicitar datos para comprobar elementos vacíos y luego enviar todos ya procesados. Es un poco más engorroso y también no parece ser una alternativa buena principalmente porque se hacen consultas adicionales. A diferencia de SQL con IF NULL, esta parece una solución poco práctica, pero funciona. Igualmente muchas gracias por la idea!